# google-maps-api-v3 getProjection

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps projection method to calculate the distance between two latitude and longitude.

var projection = this.overlay.getProjection();

var projection only gives results when the user stops moving (dragend) or zooming in and out the map.

But it doesnot work on idle.

Let say map is initialize and no event is fired than projection does not gives any result. As there is some event projection will start giving the results.

Anybody has any idea on this issue or how to trigger some event by code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry for mistyped .. 

overlay is the google overlayview object as per

this.overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the projection of a `OverlayView`-instance isn't available until the `onAdd`-method of the overlay has been executed.

observe the `projection_changed`-event of the overlay

```
   google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this.overlay, 'projection_changed',function(){
     console.log(this.getProjection());
   });
```